# HTML Email Breaking in Outlook 2013

Tags: html, email, outlook

Outlook 2013 keeps breaking and adding spaces to my table. Specifically where the table had two images side by side columns. How can I resolve this?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
<table width="900" height="2089" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; table-layout:fixed; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" height="705" width="900" style="white-space: nowrap;"><table width="900" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; table-layout:fixed; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td valign="top" width="900" height="705" colspan="2" style="line-height: 705px; white-space:nowrap"><img src="MG_PostCom_01.jpg" width="900" height="705" alt="Great SKO!" style="margin:0; border:0; padding:0; display:block; outline:none;"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td valign="top" width="900" height="750" colspan="2" style="line-height: 750px; white-space:nowrap"><img src="MG_PostCom_02.jpg" width="900" height="750" alt="Network" style="margin:0; border:0; padding:0; display:block; outline:none;"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td valign="top" width="450" height="310" style="line-height: 310px; white-space:nowrap; vertical-align:middle"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="MG_PostCom_03.jpg" width="450" height="310" alt="Connect" style="margin:0; border:0; padding:0; border:none; display:block; outline:none;"/></a></td>
            <td valign="top" width="450" height="310" style="line-height: 310px; white-space:nowrap; vertical-align:middle"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="MG_PostCom_04.jpg" width="450" height="310" alt="Message" style="margin:0; border:0; padding:0; display:block; outline:none;"/></a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td valign="top" colspan="2" width="900" height="324" style="line-height: 324px; white-space:nowrap"><img src="MG_PostCom_05.jpg" width="900" height="324" alt="SKO 2018" style="margin:0; border:0; padding:0; outline:none; display:block"/></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what's the scenario? what exactly are you doing when this happens?

Comment: @Ricardo Pontual After "MG_PostCom_02.jpg" adds a space under it, before the table under it which is spit into two columns. It also shifts the right column over to the right like this image. http://thisisdba.com/Test/image003.jpg